# PHP looping array and make <ul> issue

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

Out put from this php array as below:

```
$data[$parent][] = ['id'=>$id, 'pageName'=>$pageName];

[1] => Array
    (
      [0] => Array
          (
              [id] => 2
              [pageName] => #
          )

      [1] => Array
          (
              [id] => 8
              [pageName] => #
          )
    )

[2] => Array
    (
      [0] => Array
          (
              [id] => 3
              [pageName] => item-add-new
          )

      [1] => Array
          (
              [id] => 4
              [pageName] => item-view
          )
    )

[8] => Array
    (
      [0] => Array
          (
              [id] => 9
              [pageName] => purchase-add-new
          )

      [1] => Array
          (
              [id] => 10
              [pageName] => purchase-view
          )
    )
```

Looping this array, just I need to make a `<ul>` as below:

```
<ul>
  <li class='nav-item active'>
    <a href='#' class='nav-link'>Page Name</a>
    <ul class='submenu-inner'>
      <li><a href='#' class='nav-link'>Sup Page Name</a></li>                               
      <li><a href='#' class='nav-link'>Sup Page Name</a></li>                               
    </ul>
  </li>   

  <li class='nav-item'>
    <a href='#' class='nav-link'>Page Name</a>
    <ul class='submenu-inner'>
      <li><a href='#' class='nav-link'>Sup Page Name</a></li>                               
      <li><a href='#' class='nav-link'>Sup Page Name</a></li>                               
    </ul>
  </li> 
</ul>
```

My question is, When looping the array, I need to add css class [`.active`] to parent `<li>` to make it active. When adding this it needs to compare `pageName` from array and the variable of value of open page name.

Eg: `$p = "item-add-new";`

This is How I tried it, From this code I can get my `<ul>` but, I can't put `.active` css class to parent `<li>`.

```
foreach ($data[1] as $main) {
    $sel1 = $p == $main['pageName'] ? 'nav-item active' : 'nav-item'; 
    $menuHtml .=  "<li class='$sel1'>
                      <a href='#' class='nav-link'>Page Name</a>
                      <ul class='submenu-inner'>";
        foreach ($data[$main['id']] as $sub) {
            $menuHtml .=  "<li><a href='$sub[pageName]' class='nav-link'>Sup Page Name</a></li>";
        }        
    
        $menuHtml .= "  </ul>
                     </li>";
}
```

Hope somebody may guide me to right direction. Thank you.

Comment: I cannot see $page_url in your $data array. Can you add sample data in your php code

Comment: @MohdAlomar, It was my mistake, It should be `pageName`. Updated my question

Comment: Can you add the HTML output for your code

Comment: @MohdAlomar already added to my question.

Comment: it written that this HTML what you need but I am asking for the current HTML generated by your PHP.

Comment: The question says: "When adding this it needs to compare page_url from array and the variable of value of open page url." Where is `page_url` in the array?

Comment: All the `pageName`  in `$data[1]` are just `#`.

Comment: @Barmar, `page_url` should be `pageName`. page name belong only to sup pages, not to parent. Thats why I added `#` to parent `<a>`

Comment: So you shouldn't be checking `$main['pageName']`. You need to search `$data[$main['id']]` to see if it contains a matching pageName.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to search the sub-items to see if they contain the matching `pageName`, not compare with `$main['pageName']`.

Replace

```
$sel1 = $p == $main['pageName'] ? 'nav-item active' : 'nav-item';
```

with

```
$sel1 = in_array($p, array_column($data[$main['id']], 'pageName')) ? 'nav-item active' : 'nav-item';
```

You could also use a `foreach` loop.

```
$sel1 = 'nav-item';
foreach ($data[$main['id']] as $sub) {
    if ($sub['pageName'] == $p) {
        $sel1 = 'nav-item active';
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thans again, I works perfectly. I didn't know to use `array_column()` in that way.

Comment: You could also just use a `foreach()` loop to search each element (I original did it that way in my answer).

Comment: Its good if you can add it also into your answer as other way

Comment: I added it to the answer.